# Update a jar in a ear from command line

Tags: java, linux, jar, extract, ear

I have an ear file **MY.ear** which has a jar **HIS.jar** and in this jar I want to update a file **file.txt**

I know I could extract the jar first

```
jar xvf MY.ear lib/HIS.jar
```

Then extract the file itself

```
jar xvf HIS.jar file.txt
```

then update the jar and then the ear.

Is it possible to update the file directly or at least extract that file directly from the ear?

Comment: I only know how to do this elegantly with 7-zip, but this will involve the GUI and is a manual approach.

Comment: Probably you have to go what you have written.